# how to format asus rog gl753vd?

Tags: formatting, format, asus-laptop, windows-installer

I recently bought a new laptop, it came with windows 10 home single language, after a few days of usage and due to my work I needed to install windows 10 pro (or Linux) to try to avoid issues with the drivers I decided to go for windows 10 pro, the problem, it was a pain to mame the laptop boot from a usb stick, the bios was very confusing about this option, the only bootable device was something called "windows boot manager" after disabled various "security options" I was able to start and format the hd with a windows 10 installer (it has multiple versions home and pro) and usually asks for the version to install in the machine, but this time it did not ask, just installed windows 10 home (whaaat?) and in somehow restored the previous windows key (oem key) I don't understand how was that possible, I'm thinking im reformat with Linux to wipe out the hd and remove the previous windows flavor.

Have you experienced something like this? 
What can I do to install a different version of windows? 
Does this windows version keynis kept in the bios?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this windows version key is kept in the bios?

It's less that the windows key is in the bios and more that Win10 uses hardware verification to activate on a given machine. Your laptop has only ever had Win10 Home installed on it, and is only activated for that product. If you had bought it with Win10 Pro, the same would apply the other way around; you would not be able to downgrade to the Home version.

> but this time it did not ask, just installed windows 10 home (whaaat?) and in somehow restored the previous windows key (oem key)

That would be the installation media checking your hardware for authentication signatures. It found them and loaded the matching version of Windows.

> I'm thinking im reformat with Linux to wipe out the hd and remove the previous windows flavor.

That won't make a difference, there's no Win10 Pro key associated with your laptop. The same thing that you detailed in your question will happen again.

> What can I do to install a different version of windows?

You've got to buy a different version of Windows, sorry man. You mentioned you need it for work, maybe your work or school can help cover the cost. Best of luck.